# Shapefile not loading all points in ArcGIS .net

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, arcgis-api-wpf

I am trying to load a shapefile into my WPF .Net framework application. I can load the file successfully however it only shows a few points of the shapefile.

For testing I loaded the same shapefile to QGIS and I get the same results from QGIS, same points. It is interesting because if I load the .zip file into QGIS I get all the points in the file.

Essentially I am trying to load this shapefile with all points into my WPF application using ArcGIS runtime WPF.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           MapPoint mapCenterPoint = new MapPoint(-118.805, 34.027, SpatialReferences.Wgs84);
           MainMapView.SetViewpoint(new Viewpoint(mapCenterPoint, 100000));
           Initialize();

       }
       
   

   private async void Initialize()
   {
           // Create a new map to display in the map view with a streets basemap
           MainMapView.Map = new Map(BasemapStyle.ArcGISStreets);

           // Get the path to the downloaded shapefile
           string filepath = @"Airports\airports.shp";

       try
       {
           // Open the shapefile
           ShapefileFeatureTable myShapefile = await ShapefileFeatureTable.OpenAsync(filepath);

           // Create a feature layer to display the shapefile
           FeatureLayer newFeatureLayer = new FeatureLayer(myShapefile);

               // Add the feature layer to the map
               MainMapView.Map.OperationalLayers.Add(newFeatureLayer);

           // Zoom the map to the extent of the shapefile
           await MainMapView.SetViewpointGeometryAsync(newFeatureLayer.FullExtent, 50);
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "Error");
       }
   }

   
   }
}
```

Comment: Are you really using the 10.1 version that you have tagged?

Comment: No I actually do not think I am. I am new to GIS so I think I confused arcgis 10.1 with version 110.14.0 of the Runtime WPF package. I figured out how to get all the points to show in WPF but I had to set the CRS in QGIS first then export to my app. I wonder if there is a way to set the CRS within the WPF API